# i am using Command line dataloader in Salesforce & create simple “process-conf.xml” file ,i want to give relative path insted of absolute path

Tags: salesforce

I am using Command line data loader in Salesforce & create simple “`process-conf.xml`” file , I want to access csv file with relative path.

**For Example:**

`<entry key="dataAccess.name"  value="\Users\User\Desktop\Data Loader sample1\CSV Files\insertAccounts.csv"/>`

And process.bat file is present in :-

```
C:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

process-conf.xml doesn't seem to allow relative paths so you'll have to script something prior to launching process.bat. Here's one solution, which involves creating a template, then using ant to substitute values:

https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/scripting-the-apex-data-loader-via-ant/